# Dual monitors with xrandr

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I have a laptop with a GTX 660M. For a while I used only one monitor connected via VGA, but in order to make it work I created the following script that I made it auto run on startup:

```
#!/bin/bash
DISPLAY=:0
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00" 173.00 1920 2048 2248 2576 1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode VGA-1-1 1920x1080_60.00
```

Now I connected the 2nd external monitor via HDMI, but I can't get past `could not set configuration for CRT 65`

Running `xrandr -q` returns

```
VGA-1-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
1024x768         60.00
800x600  60.32 56.25
848x480  60.00
640x480  59.94
1920x1080_60.00 59.96*
HDMI-1-1 connected
1920x1080        60.00 +
1280x1024        75.02 60.02
1152x864         75.00
1024x768         75.03 60.00
800x600  75.00 60.32
640x480  75.00 59.94
720x400  70.08
DP-1-1 disconnected
1920x1080_60.00 (0x2e0) 173.000MHz -HSync +VSync
         h: width 1920 start 2048 end 2248 total 2576 skew 0 clock 67.16KHz
         v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1120           clock 59.96Hz
```

Still, 2nd monitor doesn't even start. I tried adding it with `xrandr --addmode HDMI-1-1 1920x1080_60.00` but the same error with `configuration for crt65` happened.

I have no more clues about what I can do. Suggestions?
Using Ubuntu 16.10

P.S. nVidia optimus doesn't even detect any monitor, so no point in even trying.

Comment: Worth to mention: disconnecting one monitor automatically enables the other one. I just can't get both of them working.